# SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) generating excpetion dbus[3856] about dbus library

Tags: 32bit-64bit, sdl-2, dbus

I developed a C++ application that among others use SDL2.

It compiles and run on Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit machine) and on OSX.

When I try to compile the application on a computer on chip running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 in a 32 bits machine with the libraries compiled by me, it returns an exception.

The exception is happening inside the line `SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO )` and the message is the following:

```
dbus[3856]: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-message.c ine 1362.
This is normally a bug in some application using D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print backtrace.
Aborted
```

It seems a problem happening on Ubuntu running on a 32 bit machine. Have anyone had the same problem?

How can I solve this problem? Or does anyone know what is generating it?

**NOTE 1**
Running in `gdb` and using `backtrace` as suggested:

```
#0  0xb613d206 in __libc_do_syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S:47
#1  0xb614ab32 in __libc_signal_restore_set (set=0xbeffe3a4) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nptl-signals.h:80
#2  0xb614ab32 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:48
#3  0xb614b82e in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#4  0xb2adddf0 in _dbus_abort () at /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-1.so.3
#5  0xb2ad7c5a in _dbus_warn_check_failed () at /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-1.so.3
#6  0xb2ad8104 in _dbus_warn_return_if_fail () at /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-1.so.3
#7  0xb2acce80 in dbus_message_new_method_call () at /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdbus-1.so.3
#8  0xb68acdba in  () at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
```

**NOTE 2**
The same happens if I install SDL from the repository instead of building it.

Comment: It would probably be best to build SDL with debugging symbols and run program in debugger to at least get informative stacktrace.

Comment: I think I already built SDL library with debugging symbol using `cmake -DMCAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`: isn't this the command? I did not built at all dbus because it is not used directly by my procject but it is used indirectly by SDL.

Comment: Something like that, yes. Should be enough, I don't think you need dbus symbols. Link with that library and run in debugger (e.g. `gdb`), and when it aborts - issue `backtrace` command. Make sure your program uses your custom built libSDL with `ldd ./your_program`, if not - correct that with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/directory/with/libsdl` (this is not persistent - only affects current shell). Backtrace should give you callchain inside SDL - which may lead to some insight over why this problem happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution so anybody with a better one would be welcome.

As @Keltar suggested in the comment I debugged it with `gdb` and backtrace as already said in the question. The last line of backtrace got me suspicious:

```
#8  0xb68acdba in  () at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
```

which suggested it is not taking the library built by me but the one installed with `apt`. I checked all the paths in `Makefile` and everything was pointing to my custom built. So I checked the dynamic library files `*.so` and I found the situation was the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 odroid odroid    4096 Oct 15 12:21 cmake
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odroid odroid      17 Oct 15 12:21 libSDL2-2.0d.so -> libSDL2-2.0d.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odroid odroid      21 Oct 15 12:21 libSDL2-2.0d.so.0 -> libSDL2-2.0d.so.0.8.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 odroid odroid 4317020 Oct 15 12:21 libSDL2-2.0d.so.0.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odroid odroid      15 Oct 15 12:40 libSDL2-2.0.so -> libSDL2-2.0d.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 odroid odroid 7593354 Oct 15 12:21 libSDL2d.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 odroid odroid    4754 Oct 15 12:19 libSDL2maind.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odroid odroid      14 Oct 15 13:38 libSDL2.so -> libSDL2-2.0.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 odroid odroid    4096 Oct 15 12:21 pkgconfig
```

Note that for the symbolic link file `libSDL2.so -> libSDL2-2.0.so`, the linked file `libSDL2-2.0.so` was not created.

My solution was to rebuild the library in `Release` mode instead of `Debug` using `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`: in that way all the files library are correct. Another solution might be to symlink the file(s) manually but is is easy to mess up something.

So it seems a bug in how SDL `cmake` write the instructions for the Debug build type because in release mode my program run.

If anyone has a better solution or find any error that I could not find please let me know.